# TreeView add item with mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a treeview binded to a recursive class and I would like to let the user add item with a button when he fly over the node (like OneNote : [image: OneNote exemple])

I tried with this code i the xaml file :

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" 
            BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Law.RootGroup.Groups}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <functions:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type law:BimFluxGroup}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">

            <Grid Margin="0,0,2,0" Background="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="LawRowHeight"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                Command="{Binding ShowPopUpCommand, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConverter}">
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBlock}}" />
                                        <Binding />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                            Command="{Binding CloseToolTipCommand, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

and with this in the cs file :

```
private ICommand _showPopUpCommand;
public ICommand ShowPopUpCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _showPopUpCommand ?? (_showPopUpCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(obj =>
        {
            if (!(obj is object[] values)) return;
            if (!(Resources["AddGroup"] is Popup)) return;
            if (!(values[1] is BimFluxGroup group)) return;

            _popup = (Popup)Resources["AddGroup"];
            _popup.DataContext = group;
            _popup.PlacementTarget = values[0] as UIElement; ;
            _popup.StaysOpen = false;
            _popup.IsOpen = true;
        }));
    }
}
```

But with that code my popup just flash constantly.

Comment: Check if `StoryBoard` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview) suits your requirement instead of Interactivity Trigger.

Comment: @user1672994 you meen to play with visibility instead of using a popup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user1672994 gave me the good tips !
I'm added my add button in the template and binded the visibility with the mouse over of the TreeView ItemTemplate.

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type law:BimFluxGroup}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,2,0" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="LawRowHeight"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button x:Name="AddGroup" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBlock Text="Add Group" FontSize="10"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="AddGroup" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```